# Is it possible to pin a task to a particular thread?

Tags: multithreading, julia

Julia's multithreading system is built atop tasks.  I can create an asynchronous task that will always run on the thread that spawned it with an `@async`.  I can create a task that can be run on *any* thread with a `Threads.@spawn`.  Or I can split up an entire `for` loop across *all* available threads using `Threads.@threads for ...`.

How can I put a task onto a particular thread of my choosing — that's not the one that created it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [ThreadPools.jl](https://github.com/tro3/ThreadPools.jl). It provides a `@tspawnat` macro that allows spawning a task on a specific thread.

**Example:** (taken from the package's README.md)

```
julia> t = @tspawnat 4 Threads.threadid()
Task (runnable) @0x0000000010743c70

julia> fetch(t)
4
```

The implementation of the macro can be found [here](https://github.com/tro3/ThreadPools.jl/blob/23d9bdd65bdef4863e36093fcb46a8bd67903210/src/macros.jl#L255).

Comment: Thanks! This package was born out of the real lack of this API in Base Julia itself; see issue [#34267](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/34267) for more details.  Note that the macro's implementation can be used in an ad-hoc manner as well — it's really just a few lines of code.  (You can ignore the whole `if $(Expr(:islocal, var))` block as that's only needed if you want enclosing `@sync` macros to wait on the task; it's just the `sticky` change and the `ccall`.)